# WPF toolkit DatePicker change default value 'show calendar'

Tags: datepicker, wpftoolkit

I'm using the latest **WPF toolkit**, specifically the `DatePicker`. Everything works fine, but when no value is provided, the default 'SHOW CALENDAR' text appears in the DatePickerTextBox.
I want to be able to change this value in WPF.

One told me to download the source, add a new Dependency property and recompile to dll. That's cool but what if new version is released?

That's why I'd like to template this control in that way, that I'll be able to override this default string. Any idea how to do that?

Thanks!

Comment: I found better solution [here on Matt Hamilton Blog](http://matthamilton.net/datepicker-watermark). Works form me excellent!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

OK. I found a solution by myself.

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type toolkit:DatePickerTextBox}">
    <Setter Property="Text" Value="Bitte wählen" />
</Style>
```

Anyways, **you have to be aware of the fact**, that there is a DependencyProperty called Watermark which should be set in place of the Text.

The problem is that with the latest MS release (about June 2009) they made this property **readonly** for some unknown reason. That means, this is the only hack I made up, although there occurs a First-time exception, because the DatePicker is trying to parse the string (he supposes the text to be a Date), but normally you won't notice it.

Another possibility is to edit directly the source code from MS and **override** the `SetWaterMark()` method + add your own Dependency Property (MyWaterMark or something). But then you cannot use the provided `dll`. They said it will come fixed **with the .NET 4 realese**, let's see.

Comment: That's good and all, but how can we incorporate this into an existing style that target Datepicker ???

Comment: This only appears to work design time in my application, as soon as I launch, the text reverts to the english one

Answer (score 7):

```
    void _datePicker1_SelectedDateChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (_datePicker1.SelectedDate != null) return;

        FieldInfo fiTextBox = typeof(DatePicker)
            .GetField("_textBox", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);

        if (fiTextBox != null)
        {
            DatePickerTextBox dateTextBox =
              (DatePickerTextBox)fiTextBox.GetValue(_datePicker1);

            if (dateTextBox != null)
            {
                PropertyInfo piWatermark = dateTextBox.GetType()
                  .GetProperty("Watermark", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);

                if (piWatermark != null)
                {
                    piWatermark.SetValue(dateTextBox, "", null);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

you'll need to hook up the Load event as well with the same code.

Comment: Well I have to admit, I like you example with Reflection.. anyways.. you need a code behind

Answer (score 0):

this works great but also you'll have to override onrender method in custom class.
In this method if you set watermark content and not the property there is no need to override OnSelectedDateChanged event.
Complete code is here:

```
    public string Watermark { get; set; }

    protected override void OnSelectedDateChanged(SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnSelectedDateChanged(e);
        //SetWatermark();
    }

    protected override void OnRender(System.Windows.Media.DrawingContext drawingContext)
    {
        base.OnRender(drawingContext);
        SetWatermark();
    }

    private void SetWatermark()
    {
        FieldInfo fiTextBox = typeof(DatePicker).GetField("_textBox", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
        if (fiTextBox != null)
        {
            DatePickerTextBox dateTextBox = (DatePickerTextBox)fiTextBox.GetValue(this);
            if (dateTextBox != null)
            {
                if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(this.Watermark))
                {
                    this.Watermark = "Custom select a date";
                }

                //PropertyInfo piWatermark = typeof(DatePickerTextBox).GetProperty("Watermark", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
                //if (piWatermark != null)
                //{
                //    piWatermark.SetValue(dateTextBox, this.Watermark, null);
                //}

                var partWatermark = dateTextBox.Template.FindName("PART_Watermark", dateTextBox) as ContentControl;
                if (partWatermark != null)
                {
                    partWatermark.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Gray);
                    partWatermark.Content = this.Watermark;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also do this:

Add a textbox and a datepicker to your form with the following settings:

In your window.xaml:

```
<TextBox x:Name="textBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="22" Margin="38,38,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"/>
    <DatePicker x:Name="datePicker" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="130,37,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="28" BorderBrush="Transparent" SelectedDateChanged="datePicker_SelectedDateChanged"/>
```

And in your window.xaml.cs:

```
private void datePicker_SelectedDateChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        textBox.Text = datePicker.SelectedDate.Value.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy");
    }
```

The result looks like this: [klick](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dCfq8.png)