# WPF toolkit, change date format in DatePicker

Tags: c#, wpf, datepicker, toolkit

default date format in DatePicker is "yyyy-mm-dd" but i need "dd-mm-yyyy". [This one solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1102042/wpf-toolkit-datepicker-change-default-value-show-calendar) doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The date is displayed using the `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture`, that is the Windows regional settings the user selected in the control panel and it seems that can't be changed. However it shouldn't really matter since it's the user preferred date/time setting.

Answer (score 4):

This is a pretty old question (marked somewhat incorrectly as "answered").
If you need to use a specific date format for the WPF DatePicker control but don't want to open up the source-code for it (which is, in fact, available for download), you can always specify the DateFormat of your entire UI, or set it for each DatePicker control.

In my app, I used the following in Application_Startup event:

```
Private Sub Application_Startup(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.StartupEventArgs) Handles MyBase.Startup

   ' other application initialization code here

   Dim culInfo As Globalization.CultureInfo = New System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-us")
   Dim dtinfo As Globalization.DateTimeFormatInfo = New System.Globalization.DateTimeFormatInfo() With {
       .ShortDatePattern = "dd-MMM-yyyy",
       .ShortTimePattern = "hh:mm:ss tt",
       .TimeSeparator = ":",
       .MonthNames = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.DateTimeFormat.MonthNames(),
       .AbbreviatedMonthNames = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.DateTimeFormat.AbbreviatedMonthNames(),
       .DateSeparator = "-"}

 culInfo.DateTimeFormat = dtinfo
 System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = culInfo
```

Note that this will set the format for short-date-format everywhere in your app (which is what I wanted, rather than going through and applying the culture to each and every instance of a date-picker.  I came up with the above based on another StackOverflow post; I don't remember exactly where it was (or I'd credit the author), but anyway, hope this helps!

Kirk

Comment: Thx for Your answer. Checked one was sufficient for my problem. But I will try Your way in future apps. Greets.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to give that format to your date your must do something like this:

```
DatePicker datetimepicker;
datetimepicker.SelectedDate.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

`datetimepicker.SelectedDate.Value` is a `DateTime Object` so you can manipulate as you want.

Comment: I believe the question was about changing display format in a datepicker itself.