# Datepicker Watermark

Tags: vb.net, datepicker, watermark

I found this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1102042/wpf-toolkit-datepicker-change-default-value-show-calendar) in Stackoverflow for Removing Datepicker Watermark.

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type toolkit:DatePickerTextBox}">
    <Setter Property="Text" Value="Bitte wählen" />
</Style>
```

is it possible to set above using vb.net code. 
Thank you,
Rey.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The one way I can think of to do this is using a resource dictionary.

Create a resource dictionary with that bit of XAML in it and add the dictionary to your resources on Window Initialized.  This is a nice way to change styles dynamically in WPF.

In Visual Studio, add a new Resource Dictionary and make it look like this:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:toolkit="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wpf/2008/toolkit"
                    >
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type toolkit:DatePickerTextBox}">
        <Setter Property="Text" Value="Test" />
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Then in your window add the following to add the resource dictionary to your apps resources:

```
Private Sub Window1_Initialized(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Initialized
    Dim rd As New ResourceDictionary()
    rd = CType(Application.LoadComponent(New Uri("Dictionary1.xaml", UriKind.Relative)), ResourceDictionary)
    Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Clear()
    Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(rd)
End Sub
```

If you don't want to use styles the only thing that seems to make sense then is to override the default implementation of the DatePicker and implement your own.  A good description of how to do that can be found here:

http://www.tanguay.info/web/index.php?pg=codeExamples&id=144

Comment: I want to programmatically set the text. i dont want to use any styles. Thanks for the reply..

Comment: Added another option, override their and make your own.  Not ideal but certainly doable.